# Project-Conditions multiple lines

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project that needs to different versions of a few DLLs depending on the release configuration.

Usually I would do that the following way:

```
<Reference Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'V16Release|AnyCPU' " Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.16.1.5626.1200\lib\net45\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'V16Release|AnyCPU' " Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.16.1.5626.1200\lib\net45\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

and this for the other Build-configuration:

```
<Reference Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'V15Release|AnyCPU' " Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.15.1.1626.1200\lib\net45\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'V15Release|AnyCPU' " Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.15.1.1626.1200\lib\net45\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

As you can see, depending on the release configuration, different DLLs are loaded.

While this works, there are more than just two packages. So is there a way to group my conditions like:

```
<Group Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'V15Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
</Group>
```

So just a simple "`if (left==right) {}`" as you would write it in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the project in an editor you'll see References are in an [ItemGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx) so you can put a condition on that, and have multiple groups with different conditions:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'V15Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
</ItemGroup >

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'V16Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
  <Reference.... />
</ItemGroup >
```